# Getting 429: Too many requests with Sheets API when within rate limit guidelines

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a Python script that is adding values from a database into Google Sheets for my team and it appears to be hitting a rate limit incorrectly. At first I was sending a request then waiting a full second before sending another so that I would stay under my 100 requests per 100 seconds limit. At first, everything was fine, ran for weeks without any issues. Now I'm hitting the rate limit all the time, so I increased it to waiting 2 seconds after every request before the next and same issue.

If I checked the Metrics of my application, I am only sending 43.3 requests per 100 seconds, yet it is still limiting me.

I attempted to make a new user account for my application just in case and still the same issue.

Any help in understanding why I keep getting limited even though it appears I'm within the limits would be appreciated.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 429,
    "message": "Quota exceeded for quota group 'WriteGroup' and limit 'Write requests per user per 100 seconds' of service 'sheets.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:734536671804'.",
    "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developer console API key",
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/project/734536671804/apiui/credential"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Code:

```
for item in items_list:
    time.sleep(2)
    my_worksheet.append_row([item[2], item[1], item[3], item[6], item[5],                    
        item[7]])
```

[Image of Google usage metrics and limits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsvJk.png)

Comment: @awson Zeugin If this is a programming question, and the script can affect what you are experiencing, you should post some code, otherwise this question is not about programming.

Comment: Hello @LawsonZeugin, from the details provided it seems that the issue is related to the code you have used. Would you mind **posting the code snippets that use the Sheets API**? That would be of great help in diagnosing your issue! Cheers!

Comment: @LawsonZeugin Which version of the **Sheets API** are you using? Cheers!